# why does this form not take data from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I would like to capture email addresses with this form:

I have decided to create a model only for this and use the views and controller for a different model that is serving only static assets (think: newsletter sign-up).

```
<%= form_for (@signup) do |f| %>
 <% if @signup.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
   <p><%= pluralize(@signup.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</p>

   <ul>
    <% @signup.errors.full_messages.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email_address %><br />
  <%= f.email_field_tag :email_address %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
```

How do I get this form to work? I get `undefined method signups_path for #<#<Class:0x00000004f1feb0>:0x00000004f09a98>` exception, which is understandable (its looking for a SignupsController by convention).

But I want the form to display in a separate controller I call `PagesController` and send it to the Signup model.

Additional Info:

I tried passing **url: pages_path** in the form and get the same exception.

```
 # view inside PagesController
 <div class="four columns">
   <%= render 'form' %> 
 </div>

#stub of model
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @signup = Signup.new
 end

def create
 @signup = Signup.new(params[:signup])
end
end
```

Comment: Did you set up the routes? Add them to the question + update the form with `url: pages_path` please

Comment: Can you show your class definition for SignUp?  I think it needs to be ActiveModel

Comment: + change `f.email_field_tag` to `f.email_field` + save `@signup` in PagesController#create and `redirect_to` somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<%= form_for @sighup, :url => {:controller => :pages, :action => :index} do |f| %>
```

and I hope you didn't forget the

```
<% end %>
```